# 5b5d url php форма

Tags: php

Имеется форма

```
<form method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]">
</form>
```

При сабмите формы, странным образом генерируется url:

```
site.com?filter%5B%5D=1&array%5B%5D=1
```

Как избавиться от этого символа `%5B%5D`?

Comment: `urldecode` .....http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

Никак, при текущем коде формы. Это конвертация параметров формы в приемлемый вид для отправки на сервер (см. urlencode, urldecode). Ваши данные выглядят вот так после декодирования:

```
filter[]=1&array[]=1
```

Вы передайте 2 массива, если не хотите использовать массивы, то уберите в name поля [ ]